# Need help sorting a Struct by Timestamp in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

Trying to sort a Swift struct by timestamp and really need some help. My struct definition is as follows:

```
struct TripDetails {

  let tripDepartureTime: String
  var myLocations: [GeoPoint]
  var myDates: [Timestamp]

}
```

And in the variable todaysTrip is the following data:

```
TripDetails(
tripDepartureTime: "2020-05-23 22:56:52 +0000", 

myLocations: [<FIRGeoPoint: (21.561333, -80.033536)>, 
<FIRGeoPoint: (22.561288, -80.023592)>, 
<FIRGeoPoint: (20.561265, -80.063439)>], 

myDates: [<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1590274922 nanoseconds=795317000>, 
<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1590274802 nanoseconds=683353000>, 
<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1590274682 nanoseconds=679319000>])
```

I want to sort **all the fields** of the particular trip based on the times of the myDates timestamp in descending order. Been at it for awhile and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've seen several posts here on StackOverflow dealing with this question but none of them seem to work in my case.

Comment: You don't really have a type stamp, you have a `String`. At the boundary where this data enters your application, you should parse that string into a more appropriate data type, `Date` in this case. Then sorting this is as trivial as `trips.sorted { $0.departureTime < $1.departureTime }`.

Comment: you can zip your arrays together and then sort it `let sorted = zip(tripDetails.myLocations,tripDetails.myDates).sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }` 
`let locations = sorted.map(\.0)` 
`let dates = sorted.map(\.1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you to change structure of your model:

```
struct TripDetails {
    struct LocationInfo {
        var location: GeoPoint
        var timestamp: TimeStamp
    }

    let tripDepartureTime: String
    var locations: [LocationInfo]

}
```

Sorting:

```
var tripDetails = ... // Getting model
tripDetails.locations.sort(by: { $0.timestamp.seconds > $1.timestamp.seconds })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But does that sort all the arrays in the structure, or just the muDates array?

Comment: It sorts only myDates array.

Comment: oh, I actually need to reorder all the fields, based on the descending order of the myDates timestamps

Comment: Why not sort on timestamp directly?